# Finishing up the junction box

Tags: recessed-lighting

Inspector said something was required in the hole that was punched out to run the romex through. (hole can not be left with just romex)  anyone know what I need to buy?

Answer (score 4):

You need a strain relief clamp

[image: strain clamp1]

or cable gland

[image: cable gland]

*(images for example, not an endorsement)*

Since it's NM-B, the top one. The bottom one is for round cordage.

Comment: But these require completed electrical connections to be undone. Are there types that slip over the wire outside the box and are then tightened so the wires don't  have to be disconnected and pulled out?

Comment: Thank you, will check to see if there are ones that can be applied post wiring, if not par for the course :)